# dired+ does not respect listing dired-listing-switches

Tags: dired

I'm having problems getting dired to list directory contents correctly after I install dired+. To demonstrate, below is an example of how dired lists directory contents *before* installing dired+:

[image: Before installing dired]

This is what I expect. Furthermore, I've updated my .emacs file to use the following listing switches:

```
(setq dired-listing-switches "-alh")
```

Now, after I install dired+, my dired-listing-switches are not respected anymore. Below is an image that shows how dired lists directory contents *after* I install dired+

[image]

I have added the following to my .emacs file

```
(require 'dired+)
(setq dired-listing-switches "-alh")
```

I should mention that I'm using GNU Emacs 26.0.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2016-10-22.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Chakravarthy provided most of the answer.

1. **`(`** is a keyboard shortcut for using menu **Dir** > **Hide/Show** > **Hide/Show Details**.
2. [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) does not impose this default behavior of hiding details. You can customize the initial behavior (details hidden or not).  These options control the behavior of hiding and showing details (`C-h v` for each option tells you this):

   > **diredp-hide-details-initially-flag** is a variable defined in **`dired+.el`**.
   >   Its value is t
   >
   > Documentation:
   >   Non-nil means hide details in Dired from the outset.
   >
   > **diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag** is a variable defined in **`dired+.el`**.
   >   Its value is t
   >
   > Documentation:
   >   Non-nil means display the next Dired buffer the same way as the last.
   >   The last `dired-hide-details-mode` value set is used by the next Dired
   >   buffer created.

Comment: Thanks! Adding (setq diredp-hide-details-initially-flag nil) (setq diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag nil) to my .emacs file gives me exactly what I want!

Answer (score 1):

That's how `dired+` looks by default. To get it to view more details (like vanilla `dired-mode`), select  `Dir` (in menu) -> `Hide/Show` -> `Hide/Show Details()`